# How can I find a col outside row, but inside page wrapper with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, console

I have a way to long source, and I can't see a col which standalone in main div (id=page-wrapper).

I can use chrome developer tools for select this element with jquery, but I don't know how, becouse if I mark target something like this:

`$("#page-wrapper .col-md-4")` the script find a col-md-4 in a  row, which not realy big help for me.
So I would like to something like this:

```
$("not::#page-wrapper .row .col-*").selectThis("#page-wrapper .col-*")
```

"*" mean any character after "-" becouse I don't know which cell standalone.
After if I can select this element, I would like to add css background atribute for I can highlight div.

Comment: Can you give an example in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the source in a fidlle might've been helpful here.

But still, try these and see if you find it:

`$('#page-wrapper').siblings('.col-md-4')`

`$('#page-wrapper').parents('.col-md-4')`

`$('#page-wrapper').closest('.col-md-4')`

All of the above will look outside the `#page-wrapper` but in different ways.

EDIT: after your jsbin, I've made an example here: http://jsbin.com/daqinizide/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Hope that helps.

Comment: md-4 is just a example,
As I mention that I dosen't know wich col outside of the div.
That's wy I need to something which ="*" to end

Comment: If you don't now what tag your elemnt is or what class you have assigned to it, how do you expect to find it at all? .col-md-4 is a placeholder. Try different things with it like div, .col-* etc

As for the '*' you can do .col* to find all elements having classes that start with '.col'

Comment: I just don't whanted try out all coll format what we have.
For example in windows, you can use *.jpg to find jpg elements.
My thinkig is something simular for colls.

Comment: The asterixs didn't show in my previous comment. You can do .col[asterix](remove the square brackets)

Comment: Can you create a jsbing based on this example?
http://jsbin.com/madomopujo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi InBug, I just made an edit to my answer with the jsBin. I'm sorry about the asterix  earlier I was confusing that with something else. jsBin has the correct answer

Comment: You see the problem?
That's every col is highlighted.
I only one coll need to be highlihted, that's inside page-wrapper but not inside the row..
And that's col a unkow col-SOMETHGING

Comment: change the js to this: 
$("#page-wrapper>div[class^='col']").css('background', 'red');

Comment: Ah!
Thank you that was I need for me!

Comment: If you aded this to answer I can acept that!

Comment: I added it to the answer also :)

Comment: don't forget change link to:
http://jsbin.com/zirasiviki/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thats ok, I cloned a copy and gave it there.

Comment: Hahaha, no problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, get direct child elements of #pagewrapper:

```
$('#page-wrapper > .col-md-*');
```

Comment: I also need* for select any element "col-"

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, then why dosen't work in this example?
http://jsbin.com/yemubecaqe/edit?html,js,output